# How to apply a polygon mask layer in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm looking to crop the density plot to only land while keeping to `sf`.

Here's a simple example problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(albersusa)
library(ggthemes)
library(jsonlite)

dat <-
  fromJSON(
    "https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/arcgis/rest/services/Fortune_500_Corporate_Headquarters/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,NAME,PROFIT&outSR=4326&f=json"
  )

dat <- as.data.frame(dat$features$attributes)

top_50 <- dat %>%
  arrange(desc(PROFIT)) %>%
  head(50)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa_sf()) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE),
                         data = top_50,
                         alpha = .5) +
  xlim(-125,-66.5) +
  ylim(20, 50) +
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Not sure if I'm getting close to a solution but here's some of the code I've been trying:

```
test <- (MASS::kde2d(
  top_50$LONGITUDE, top_50$LATITUDE,
  lims =  c(-125,-66.5, 20, 50)
))

ggpoly2sf <- function(poly, coords = c("long", "lat"),
                      id = "group", region = "region", crs = 4326) {
  sf::st_as_sf(poly, coords = coords, crs = crs) %>% 
    group_by(!! as.name(id), !! as.name(region)) %>% 
    summarize(do_union=FALSE) %>%
    sf::st_as_sf("POLYGON") %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(!! as.name(region)) %>%
    summarize(do_union = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup()
}

v <- contourLines(test)
vv <- v
for (i in seq_along(v)) vv[[i]]$group <- i
vv <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vv, as.data.frame))

dsi_sf <- ggpoly2sf(vv, coords = c("x", "y"), region = "level") %>% st_as_sf()

usa <- usa_sf()

dsi_i_sf <- st_intersection(usa$geometry, dsi_sf)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=usa) +
  geom_sf(data=dsi_i_sf,color="red") +
  geom_density2d_filled(aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE),
                 data = top_50,alpha=.4) +
  xlim(-125,-66.5) +
  ylim(20, 50) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: This is currently a hard task in R. Non-rectangular clipping mask are coming to R4.1.0 but they don't exist in the grid system now. See https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/GraphicsEngine/definitions/definitions.html, in particular the first example and footnote.

Comment: I've been working with `sf::st_intersection` but I'm struggling to produce the density plot outside of ggplot. Seems like it's the current working answer: http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/classes/STAT4580-2020/maps.html

Comment: I'm clueless about the sf framework, but doesn't looking at ggplot2's [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/241b7c5b301936d208481c09346df713dc34cd59/R/stat-density-2d.r#L165-L186) allow you to reconstruct the process?

Comment: It's easy enough to implement `MASS::kde2d()` but manipulating the output into a meaningful layer for intersection is a long road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mask layer over the US with AK & HI inset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(albersusa) 
library(ggthemes)
library(jsonlite)
library(spatstat)


dat <-
  fromJSON(
    "https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/arcgis/rest/services/Fortune_500_Corporate_Headquarters/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,NAME,PROFIT&outSR=4326&f=json"
  )

dat <- as.data.frame(dat$features$attributes)

top_50 <- dat %>%
  arrange(desc(PROFIT)) %>%
  head(50)

usa <- usa_sf()

top50sf <- st_as_sf(top_50, coords = c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(usa))

# usa polygons combined
usa_for_mask <- usa_sf() %>%
  st_geometry() %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  st_union()

# bounding box of us & inset AK + HI,
# expand as needed 
us_bbox <- st_bbox(usa_for_mask) %>%
             st_as_sfc() %>% 
             st_as_sf()

us_mask <- st_difference(us_bbox, usa_for_mask)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE),
                         data = top_50,
                         alpha = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = us_mask, fill = 'white') +
  xlim(-125,-66.5) +
  ylim(20, 50) +
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

You can expand the bounding box to get rid of the purple border around the plot.

This does what you're asking for, but almost certainly isn't spatially accurate.  It can get a point across to a general audience, but don't make any big decisions based on it.

More accurate spatial interpolation methods can be found here:

https://rspatial.org/raster/analysis/4-interpolation.html

https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/interpolation-in-r.html

Answer (score 2):

Create a rectangle of the same plot dimensions:

```
rec_box <- data.frame(x=c(-125,-125,-66.5,-66.5,-125), y=c(20,50,50,20,20))
```

Create an outline of the US and extract only the lat/lon points into a dataframe:

```
outline <- map("usa", plot=FALSE)

outline <- data.frame(x=outline$x,y=outline$y)
```

Bind the two together to create a polygon with a hole in the middle:

```
mask <- rbind(rec_box,outline)
```

Add a `geom_polygon()` to plot the mask data and color appropriately:

```
  geom_polygon(data=mask,
                aes(x=x,y=y),color="white",fill="white")
```

Everything combined:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(albersusa)
library(ggthemes)
library(jsonlite)

dat <-
  fromJSON(
    "https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/arcgis/rest/services/Fortune_500_Corporate_Headquarters/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,NAME,PROFIT&outSR=4326&f=json"
  )

dat <- as.data.frame(dat$features$attributes)

top_50 <- dat %>%
  arrange(desc(PROFIT)) %>%
  head(50)

usa <- usa_sf()

outline <- map("usa", plot=FALSE)

outline <- data.frame(x=outline$x,y=outline$y)

rec_box <- data.frame(x=c(-125,-125,-66.5,-66.5,-125), y=c(20,50,50,20,20))

mask <- rbind(rec_box,outline)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = usa_sf()) +
  geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x = LONGITUDE, y = LATITUDE),
                         data = top_50,
                         alpha = .5) +
  xlim(-125,-66.5) +
  ylim(20, 50) +
  geom_polygon(data=mask,
                aes(x=x,y=y),color="white",fill="white") +
  theme_map() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Really a thing of beauty.