# Daisychain connect multiple polygons by single nearest points

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, r-sf

I'm looking to create a masking polygon for multiple polygons.

It's easy enough for a single polygon:

[How to apply a polygon mask layer in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911086/how-to-apply-a-polygon-mask-layer-in-ggplot)

but much trickier for multiple:

[https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/GraphicsEngine/definitions/definitions.html](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epaul/Reports/GraphicsEngine/definitions/definitions.html)

I feel like I'm fairly close but I need a method of drawing a line between a point for the closest polygon, i.e. I'd like to try and connect nearest islands with a line.

[image]

While also connecting those polygons to an outer polygon box but only with a single line:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(albersusa)

usa <- usa_sf()

HI <- st_coordinates(usa %>%
                             filter(name %in% c("Hawaii"))) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        select(X, Y)


rec_box <-
        data.frame(
                X = c(-108,-108,-101,-101,-108),
                Y = c(24, 28, 28, 24, 24)
        )

mask <- rbind(HI, rec_box)

eg <- st_as_sf(data.frame(mask), coords = c("X", "Y"))
poly <- st_convex_hull(eg)

ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = poly) +
        geom_density2d_filled(data = HI, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
        geom_polygon(data = mask,
                     aes(x = X, y = Y),
                     color = "black",
                     fill = "white")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*:
For only a mask around the islands:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(albersusa)
#library(concaveman)
#library(nngeo)

usa <- usa_sf()

# keep only the geometry from Hawaii (not the data)
HI <- usa %>%
       filter(name %in% c("Hawaii")) %>%
       st_cast('POLYGON') %>% 
       st_geometry() %>% 
       st_as_sf()


# HI as dataframe as your example
HI2 <- st_coordinates(usa %>%
        filter(name %in% c("Hawaii"))) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        select(X, Y)
# you may need a larger box. This uses sf:st_bbox to get exact
#  rectangle of the polygons. adjust accordingly
hi_box <- st_bbox(HI) %>% st_as_sfc() %>% st_as_sf()

# find the difference betwee HI & hi_box
hi_mask <- st_difference(hi_box, st_union(HI))


ggplot() +
  geom_density_2d_filled(data = HI2, aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_sf(data = hi_mask, fill = 'black')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you're happy with the HI mask created above, you can connect it to your defined bounding box using a single line with `nngeo::st_connect()`.

This should find the shortest connecting line between the two.  If you prefer the connecting line to be at a specific point (southwest corner in your example above), supply it as an `sf` object to the `st_connect()` function instead of the entire box.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(albersusa)
library(concaveman)
library(nngeo)

usa <- usa_sf()

# Hawaii, cast to POLYGON rather than the original MULTIPOLYGON
HI <- (usa %>%
       filter(name %in% c("Hawaii"))) %>%
       st_cast('POLYGON')

connected_HI <- concaveman(HI)

# rec box as an sf object with same crs as HI
rec_box <-
  data.frame(X = c(-108, -108, -101, -101, -108),
             Y = c(24, 28, 28, 24, 24)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('X', 'Y'
  )) %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(HI))

# connecting HI mask you made to your rec_box
connected_to_rec_box <- nngeo::st_connect(st_zm(connected_HI), rec_box)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = connected_HI, fill = 'turquoise', alpha = .4) +
  geom_sf(data = connected_to_rec_box, color = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Is there any way to connect the polygons with a line between two points versus the three point wedge currently?

Comment: @SCDCE Probably using a similar method. I'll take a look when I have a chance. Do they need to be connected? An unconnected sf object may work.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit to add another layer. Ultimately, I'm trying to create a mask for something like a `geom_density()` so it is only shown on land. In my previous linked post, I achieved this with the US by connecting the two polygons to make a hole, I'm not sure of another method but of course would be open to any method if it does the job.

Comment: @SCDCE See edit for a mask (inverse mask?) over only the land of the islands.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you. Don't suppose you'd want to post an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911086/how-to-apply-a-polygon-mask-layer-in-ggplot to include the insets from `usa_sf()`?

Comment: @SCDCE Sure, take a look.