# In R, is there a way to constrain stat_density_2d to a polygon/shape in an underlying JPEG?

Tags: r, jpeg, stat-density2d

In R, I am trying to run stat_density_2d on a dataset and include a jpeg (containing a polygon) underneath. However, I would like to constrain the analysis of stat_density_2d so that it fits completely within the polygon shown in the underlying jpeg. Right now, I have the results from stat_density_2d displaying outside of the polygon.

To help visualize, here is a picture of another similar example that I found online, however, my underlying image is not a map with associated coordinates. [Example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt9Sa.png)

I am not necessarily looking to just crop the analysis to the polygon shape. I would like to constrain the density plot analysis to the polygon's extent.

Any help would be appreciated, even general steps for how to move forward.

See explanation above.

Comment: I don't know how to constrain, however the technique \ search term is `masking`. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/66911086/10276092

Comment: You'll probably need to perform the 2D density kernel estimate manually and then filter out the values falling outside the polygon, then plot them manually using something like `geom_raster()`. I don't think stat_density_2d can do this automatically but the function it uses internally is `MASS::kde2d` (https://rdrr.io/cran/MASS/man/kde2d.html)